# Error adding metrix to queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, hystrix

I am using Eureka, Zuul, Hystrix and composite services in my application. RabbitMq I am using for message queuing. While running test cases, I am getting Following exceptions. My tests are running fine but getting the exception as follows :

```
11:38:16.597 [task-scheduler-4] ERROR o.s.c.n.h.amqp.HystrixStreamTask -     Error adding metrics to queue
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at  org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.amqp.HystrixStreamTask.gatherMetrics(H ystrixStreamTask.java:289) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp-  1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~ [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at  org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMeth odRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301( Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Cloud are you using? I'm getting similar error after upgrading Spring Cloud from Angel.SR4 to Brixton.M4. My RabbitMQ queue is **not** full and at least some metrics do get through.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your queue is full. Increase the queue length either using x-max-length or x-max-length-bytes property.

More information can be found [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem after upgrading Spring Cloud from `Angel.SR4` to `Brixton.M4`. Replacing maven dependency `<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>` with

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>`

seems to have solved the problem. Depending on your dependencies, this might be helpful!

A more complete look at my deps:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.netflix.hystrix.amqp.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.goldmansachs</groupId>
                <artifactId>gs-collections-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.goldmansachs</groupId>
                <artifactId>gs-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```